# edite content type style

Tags: nodes, theming

I clone content type by using bundle copy module, but the view of the content type never the same as the first one, how can I clone the style too

Comment: You should explain in detail how you have " tried to change css file and copy style p and edit p word to v". Is not clear what you've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the template also. For example if you have a `node--old-content-type.tpl.php` file you'll need to copy it to `node--new-content-type.tpl.php`.

Comment: I did it now, I clone node--old-content-type.tpl.php and renamed it to the new one, have I to edit the file inside

Comment: It depends on what is in there. It also won't pick up the new tpl.php file until you have cleared the caches and possibly rebuilt the theme registry.

Comment: i cleared cash it working fine but rate module didn't work with the content type, how can I repute for your answer ?

Comment: It works fine thx alot